# Is my teacher correct about organic compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry

So in my chem notes its written that **CCl4** , **CH2Cl2** are both organic compounds as they are derived from **CH4** which is also an organic compound.

It says that because CCl4 and CH2Cl2 are "derivatives" of CH4

Well...then lets say we involve **CH4** in a reaction and take the product and involve the product in another reaction and then take the product of that reaction too and involve *IT* in another reaction and keep on doing this 10 times and then end up with **SO2** does that mean that **SO2** is an organic compound too?

I mean if this is the definition then ANY element/compound can be termed as an organic compound right?

Please help.

Comment: sigh... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_compound

Comment: maybe she means that it only goes till 1 reaction. Like if the product of the first reaction of CH4 is another organic compound and not the consecutive reactions?

Comment: You should really check what derivative means...